# Send out 1 email after all Oozie jobs finish

Tags: email, hadoop, oozie

So far, I've been using oozie email actions to send out email enriched with some information, when submitting job in our hadoop cluster :

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
            <to>[COMMA-SEPARATED-TO-ADDRESSES]</to>
            <cc>[COMMA-SEPARATED-CC-ADDRESSES]</cc> <!-- cc is optional -->
            <subject>[SUBJECT]</subject>
            <body>[BODY]</body>
            <content_type>[CONTENT-TYPE]</content_type> <!-- content_type is optional -->
            <attachment>[COMMA-SEPARATED-HDFS-FILE-PATHS]</attachment> <!-- attachment is optional -->
        </email>
        <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
        <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

This is for sending out emails after each submitted workflows.
Let's say i have 560 jobs running and instead of receiving 560 emails, i would like to receive only 1 single email that will contain a sum up of what happened in that specific business day ( successes, failures etc..)

I am not finding any solution on how to implement this.
Has anyone already tried something like that, and if yes, could you please point me to some possible approach to this idea?
Please comment out if what i am trying to achieve is not clear enough, 
Thanks

Comment: I think you want to use Oozie fork/join operators

Comment: What you want is, basically, the Ops Console for an Enterprise Scheduler... Oozie is not "Enterprise"-grade but it has a crude UI, a crude command-line interface, and a REST API. If you insist on receiving an automated e-mail for some reason, then use a simple _CRON_ daily job on an Edge Node => dump the last 600 workflow executions via a simple `oozie` CLI command, send as e-mail attachment via `xmail`. For custom filtering and formatting, use instead Python to invoke the REST API, parse the JSON result, filter/reformat, and send via mail

Comment: In other words, don't use custom actions inside your Oozie workflows to get a global view of what happens in Oozie -- use the Oozie monitoring features, from outside.